# Text Color to Match Default UIButton Color [Blue]

Tags: iphone

The default UIButton round rectangle is that dark blue.  I want my cell's text in a table to match this blue color.

I am using this code but the only blue I can find is a bright blue...

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use this code to set the color using RGB value

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.196 green:0.3098 blue:0.52 alpha:1.0];
```

Answer (score 36):

The system button text color for iOS 7 and above is:

Swift:

```
UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.478431, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
```

Objective-C:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.478431 blue:1 alpha:1]
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. `UIColor* theColor = _yourButton.currentTitleColor; NSLog(@"title color: %@",theColor");` if further proof required.

Comment: Proof in Swift: `print(UIButton(type: .System).currentTitleColor)`

Comment: @arcadybob has the right idea. And if you don't already have a button object you can just do something like `UIColor *systemTextColor = [[[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem] titleLabel] textColor];
cell.textLabel.textColor = systemTextColor;
`

Answer (score 4):

The color in iOS6 is:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.22 green:0.33 blue:0.53 alpha:1.0]
```

Comment: do you have a source for this by chance?