# Make label blue when there's a checkmark in the cell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I know how to put a checkmark as the `acessoryView` of my `UITableViewCell`. Unlike the Settings app, my `textLabel` does not become blue when there's a checkmark next to it. Is there a simple style property I have to set for this to happen or am I forced to manually change the `textColor` property on the `textLabel`? If the latter is true, is this particular shade of blue stored as a constant somewhere?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`selectedTextColor` has been deprecated in iOS 3.0 so I think you have to use the `highlightedTextColor` property of the `UITableViewCell`'s `textLabel` property.  And I believe `[UIColor colorWithRed:50.0/255.0 green:79.0/255.0 blue:132.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]` is the correct default shade of blue that is used for highlighted text:

```
cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:50.0/255.0 green:79.0/255.0 blue:132.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
// cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.196 green:0.3098 blue:0.52 alpha:1.0];
```

[`UITableViewCell` Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/UITableViewCell_Class.pdf).

---

Yoou might also want a different cell style then the default.  `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` is what the Settings App uses:

> Cell Styles
>
> ```
>      typedef enum {
>          UITableViewCellStyleDefault,
>          UITableViewCellStyleValue1,
>          UITableViewCellStyleValue2,
>          UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
>      } UITableViewCellStyle; 
>
>      UITableViewCellStyleDefault
> ```
>
> A simple style for a cell with a text label (black and left-aligned) and an optional image view. Note
>   that this is the default style for cells prior to iOS 3.0.
>
> ```
>      UITableViewCellStyleValue1
> ```
>
> A style for a cell with a label on the left side of the cell with left-aligned and black text; on the right side is a label that has smaller blue text and is right-aligned.
>   The Settings application uses cells in this style.
>
> ```
>      UITableViewCellStyleValue2
> ```
>
> A style for a cell with a label on the left side of the cell with text that is right-aligned and blue; on
>   the right side of the cell is another label with smaller text that is
>   left-aligned and black. The Phone/Contacts application uses cells in
>   this style.
>
> ```
>      UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
> ```
>
> A style for a cell with a left-aligned label across the top and a left-aligned label below it in
>   smaller gray text. The iPod application uses cells in this style.

---

Got the color from [this SO question (text-color-to-match-default...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374341/text-color-to-match-default-uibutton-color-blue)

Comment: So the answer is "no" - I have to manually set the text color? I chose to set the text color directly with `cell.textLabel.textColor` rather than `highlightedTextColor`, because setting `cell.highlighted=YES` on a cell with style `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` places an ugly black background on the `textLabel`. Strange... I thought the Apple designers had better taste than this.

Comment: @JoJo Yea, some of the defaults are pretty ugly for a company with such a high rep for aesthetics.  But, yes, I believe this is the only way if its not setting the correct selected color by default.  Maybe check the interface builder though.  Some UI items have different states you can set properties for, not sure about a cell textLabel.  Havent used xcode 4.2, but I dont recall 4.1 having it for a cell.