# What color is the text of a default UIButton?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, uicolor

What color is the text of a default `UIButton`?  I am trying o recreate it in some table view cells but not having luck. The closest I have come is:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:51.0/255.0 blue:102.0/255.0 alpha:1];
```

Is that color, font size and style documented anywhere?

Comment: Just set it uicolor blue color.

Comment: The Hex value of the default color of an UIButton is `#007AFF`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
CGFloat red;
CGFloat green;
CGFloat blue;
CGFloat alpha;

UILabel *buttonLabel = [yourButton titleLabel];
UIColor *textColor = [buttonLabel textColor];

[textColor getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];
```

Now red, green, blue and alpha will contain the values you're looking for:

```
NSLog(@"Red: %f Green:%f Blue:%f Alpha:%f", red, green, blue, alpha);
```

For iOS 6 this will return:

```
Red:0.220000 Green:0.330000 Blue:0.530000 Alpha:1.000000
```

Answer (score 13):

This is a pretty old question but I thought I would add my own answer anyway.

If you need a custom 'text only' button on iOS 7 and up that has the same color then do not create it with `UIButton()` but with `UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System)`.

That will give you a text button with the same properties as a standard system button, including the correct color. You can then use this button as a template and change things like the font size or add an image, etc.

Comment: In Swift 3 this has become `UIButton(type: .system)`.

Answer (score 7):

1. Run a sample app with a UIButton on the simulator
2. Use spotlight to search for 'DigitalColor Meter'(with out the quotes, see below)
   [image]
3. Use the pointer to point it at the text color, this will give you the RGB Value of the text
4. The font size and other values can be found using IB.

Answer (score 1):

[Text Color to Match Default UIButton Color [Blue]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374341/text-color-to-match-default-uibutton-color-blue)

It looks like someone pulled it out programmatically, but I have not confirmed it.

Answer (score 1):

Personally what I would do is capture the color of the text in viewDidLoad using the property currentTitleColor and then use that when needed. That way you don't have to worry  about rgb and the rest.

So in the interface set up a UIColor property and Outlet for your button

```
@property (strong,nonatomic)UIColor *backToTheDefaultTextColor;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
```

In viewDidLoad get the buttons title color with

```
_backToTheDefaultTextColor = _myButton.currentTitleColor;
```

Then after you have changed the color of the title of the button and want to revert back simply put

```
_myButton.titleLabel.textColor = _backToTheDefaultColor;
```